# Getting Started - Community Cloud Package Installation

Tags: community

Can Salesforce AppExchange package be installed on Salesforce Community Cloud?

Comment: It does look a one liner question but still it seems relevant.If anyone has access to community cloud or any information about it they can share there experience rather flagging it for low quality.

Comment: Not sure if we need to merge with this question - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145568/learning-community-cloud/145572#145572